# How to make phantom types work with methods in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, methods, type-inference, contravariance, phantom-types

Consider the following program using phantom types:

```js
const strlen = (str: string) => str.length;

type Const<A, B> = { type: 'Const', value: A };

const Const = <A, B = never>(value: A): Const<A, B> => ({ type: 'Const', value });

const map = <A, B, C>(_f: (value: B) => C, { value }: Const<A, B>): Const<A, C> => Const(value);

const contramap = <A, B, C>(_f: (value: C) => B, { value }: Const<A, B>): Const<A, C> => Const(value);

const constant = Const(true);

map(strlen, constant); // works

contramap(strlen, constant); // works
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOAbApmGBeGAKBAuOU8AlmAOYCUGAfAfAHQplQAWA3AFDtQCeADsjADC4aAB4AggBoYAIRqYA3jB798AcmGQoa6QDcAhogCuyfOJgBfDu1BahI2JgnSZGGGGS7k8KlgPHTGHFyfE0xKVl5GiwlFUCNBx0YfxNLcmtbaBgAW31eN2dZaUFfAH0AM3w-QxN8GUp0GkFpJRSBC1CHQrkQ+y1Ckuo+6GqA9M5M2FtCfVz8pwiZYrLK7DbQhpolmFaa9s7+xapesKgBqOGoUZNxmwcYSf0wR0usQhvrOZxCRmlH5-SMAA9ECYAB3EDwADWEAm4BmXwQvweDieUEBIPBkJh7CAA)

The above program type checks because the correct types are inferred. The `constant` value has the inferred type `Const<boolean, never>`. The `map` function is called with the types `A = boolean`, `B = string`, and `C = number`. The `contramap` function is called with the types `A = boolean`, `B = number`, and `C = string`.

However, it would be nice to write the above expressions using methods instead of functions. Hence, I tried the following:

```js
const strlen = (str: string) => str.length;

interface Const<A, B> {
    map: <C>(f: (value: B) => C) => Const<A, C>;
    contramap: <C>(f: (value: C) => B) => Const<A, C>;
}

const Const = <A, B = never>(value: A): Const<A, B> => ({
    map: () => Const(value),
    contramap: () => Const(value)
});

const constant = Const(true);

constant.map(strlen); // works

constant.contramap(strlen); // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOAbApmGBeGAKBAuOU8AlmAOYCUGAfAfAHQplQAWA3AFDslTLwBmAQ2DIYAYXDQAPAEEANDABCNAN7sY6mAFsBAB3yTRVLH3xYAbgMQBXZPgWV0NUQ6cSoM+YY4aYoMIQFtPRgDIxNsC2tbMRdFWPFIdzkxKg4AX04-aDE3DBDkhTywZDNeI0ibfGlyfASpAppHbFUfINN4t3NLG3JZNQ0-ALbsDsSuqPJ2NPIOdizYeYF-PLqoLEIe2cX-OiCcQkYZmAB6Y5gAdxB4AGsITLclqDpB+EDdfaRUI9OYXngr9hAA)

As you can see, the `map` method works but the `contramap` method doesn't. This is because the type of `constant` is `Const<boolean, never>` and it's not refined by the method call, i.e for `map` the type is not refined to `Const<boolean, string>` and for `contramap` the type is not refined to `Const<boolean, number>`.

Because of this, either `map` or `contramap` work but not both. If the type of the object is `Const<boolean, never>` then `contramap` doesn't work. If the type of the object is `Const<boolean, unknown>` then `map` doesn't work.

How can I make both `map` and `contramap` work using methods instead of functions?

Comment: What's the purpose of `A` in the second example?

Comment: You mean the type parameter `A`? It's the type of the value stored in the `Const` abstract data type. However, we only make use of the interface of `Const` which doesn't reveal that it stores a value of type `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by making the type parameter `B`, of the `Const` interface, a phantom type.

```js
const strlen = (str: string) => str.length;

interface Const<A, B> {
    map: <B, C>(f: (value: B) => C) => Const<A, C>;
    contramap: <B, C>(f: (value: C) => B) => Const<A, C>;
}

const Const = <A, B = never>(value: A): Const<A, B> => ({
    map: () => Const(value),
    contramap: () => Const(value)
});

const constant = Const(true);

constant.map(strlen); // works

constant.contramap(strlen); // works
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOAbApmGBeGAKBAuOU8AlmAOYCUGAfAfAHQplQAWA3AFDslTLwBmAQ2DIYAYXDQAPAEEANDABCNAN7sY6mAFsBAB3ySF80VSx98WAG4DEAV2T4FldDVFOXEqDKNUOGmKDBCAW09GANvU3MrW3sxN0V48UhPOTEfdgBfTgDoMQ8MMNSFArBkC14TaLt8aXJ8JKkimmdsVT8Q80SPS2s7clk1DQCgjuwu5J6Y8kzyDnYc2AWBQIKGqCxCPrmlwLoQnEJGWZgAehOYAHcQeABrCGyPZag6Yfhg3QOkVGOzy+u79hAA)

The type parameter `B`, of the `Const` interface, is now shadowed by the type parameters of `map` and `contramap`. This makes sense because the type parameter `B`, of the `Const` interface, is a phantom type. Hence, it shouldn't be used. On the other hand, the callers of `map` and `contramap` should be able to decide what type the type parameter `B` should be instantiated with.